# Redefine PHP method with possibility to call old one

Tags: php, reflection

I have object with method1();

How can I move method1 for example to method1_origin() and create new method1 with additional functionality and possibility to call method1_origin()?

I think reflection can help, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

You can call a [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) function.

```
class new_object extends old_object
{
    function method1()
    {
        // overwrite function here
    }
    function method1_origin()
    {
        // call old function
        parent::method1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic OOP, you can find some good info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend a class

```
class core { 

        public function __construct(){}


        protected function method_orig()
        {

        }
}
```

-

```
class someclass extends core{


       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
       }

       public function method_new()
      {
          parent::method_orig(); 
      }
}
```